# Sockets in Django

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket

In my project I have users who connect to a waiting room, after a certain time, I run an algorithm and then redirect all the users to a different room. In order to this I use sockets. Until now I have been using django_channels with daphne on Asgi, however it hasn't been 100% reliable. I need something that will work all the time. I am looking for an alternative. I need it to accurately tell me who is in the room and who has left etc. The options are:

1. Pyzmq
2. websockets - https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#
3. Autobahn|Python
4. python-socketio
5. websocket-client
6. graphene
7. converse js

I would really appreciate feedback. I would prefer something which can integrate easily with django if possible. The website is up on AWS.

Thanks

Comment: If there is a api that does this together with video conf that would be the best!